# Why is this not rendered by the twig template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a Symfony application based on 2.7.3 Symfony. 
I want to overwrite this twig template which is located under:

> src/Something/Bundle/SomethingBundle/Resources/public/templates/family/custom/custom.html.twig

This file looks like this:

```
<div class="AknFieldContainer">
<div class="AknFieldContainer-header">
    <label class="AknFieldContainer-label control-label required" for="<%- fieldName%>">
        {{ form_row(form.label) }}
    </label>
</div>
<div class="AknFieldContainer-inputContainer">
    {{ form_row(form.templateCode) }}
</div>
```

But it displays

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

I have override this code in my bundle.

> src/Something/Bundle/SomethingBundle/Resources/views/category-tree/tab/property.html.twig

The only difference which I see is because this code is inside the views file. With that said, I believe that twig engine only looks inside the code inside views. I am not sure though.

Still trying to change the route from Resources/public to Resources/views, but since we are overriding, not sure that I am going to succeed. 
So with this said, how could I render something else inside my Resources file using twig ? How could I render something that is not inside the views directory ?

Comment: have you overriden the bundle correctly ?

Comment: Hello t-n-y, thanks for the response. Something else works which means that I have.

Comment: ok, try to put more infos so. Like the real names of your folders and names of the original and all that

Comment: Why this  `for="<%- fieldName%>"`, I think it should be `for="{%- fieldName%}"`

Comment: Thanks for the response YouneL, I have change it to look like yours. Also I think we have missed the point here. Because nothing is displayed as it is supposed to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try in your config.yml

`twig:
    paths: 
        '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Something/Bundle/SomethingBundle/Resources/public/templates': my_templates`

and include with `@my_templates/family/custom/custom.html.twig`

[Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/templating/namespaced_paths.html#registering-your-own-namespaces)

Comment: Hey Snegirekk, thanks for the response. 
But it doesn't work. I have registered the public/templates in the paths and this part works, but I can't include it inside the template itself. 
{{ include("@my_templates/family/custom/custom.html.twig") }} 
It still displays this inclusion as a plain html. :-/ Do you have an idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: In symfony docs for v2.7 they tell us to use {{ include("something") }}, but {% include("something") %} works for me in symfony3. {{ display_variables.only }}

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't work. Regardless of the way I put it in.

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. `%kernel.project_dir%` works for v3.3, in v2.7 need to use `%kernel.root_dir%/..`. Did you not get any errors or exceptions?

Anyway, my answer now updated, try it. I just started v2.7.3 project to test this case and it works for me.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that.. :-)

Comment: Yes, I have seen that.. :-) And I have made it properly.. Do you know where I could check, where is twig template loaded ?

Comment: You can click template icon in profiler and see somethig like this: `@my_templates/family/custom/custom.html.twig` there, if i understood u correctly.

But if you did all that we already found, i think the problem is not in template folder.

Comment: Yes, you have understand me correctly. Hmm, I can't find the template which I have added in there. This means that I didn't add it properly even though I don't have anything in the logs. Right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158591/discussion-between-snegirekk-and-nebojsa-komnenovic).